# Reversing the order of key-value in dictionary using "lambda"

Tags: python

How do I reverse the order of key-value pairs of a dictionary, in Python? For example, I have this dictionary:

```
english_spanish = {"hi": "hola", "thanks": "gracias", "yes": "si", "no": "no"}
```

I want to reverse it so that it returns:

```
english_spanish = {"hola": "hi", "gracias": "thanks", "si": "yes", "no": "no"}
```

I would like to know how can you do it using the `lampda`but i dont seem to understand how it works

Comment: Why do you want to use `lambda` (note the spelling)? The simplest solution works without it.

Comment: The simplest solution is `dict((y,x) for x,y in english_spanish.iteritems())`

Answer (score -1):

```
english_spanish = {"hi": "hola", "thanks": "gracias", "yes": "si", "no": "no"}
spanish_english = {v:k for (k, v) in english_spanish.items()}
print(spanish_english)
# {'hola': 'hi', 'no': 'no', 'gracias': 'thanks', 'si': 'yes'}
```